# Join Queries in Peewee

Tags: python, peewee, flask-peewee

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I have just started working on peewee application and little stuck with join queries. Currently, I have following models setup :

```
class Equipment(BaseModel):
    equip_id = CharField(primary_key=True)
    is_fullset = BooleanField(default=False)


class Department(BaseModel):
    dept_id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    dept_name = CharField()


class User(BaseModel):
    email = CharField(primary_key=True)
    equip_id_fk = ForeignKeyField(Equipment, related_name="equipments", null=True)
    dept_id_fk = ForeignKeyField(Department, related_name="departments")
    user_name = CharField()
```

I want to display a view/table that will hold combined information of all the table. I tried doing this like this for User and Equipment (for now) :

```
  query = (Equipment.select(Equipment, User).join(User, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER))
```

Here I get equipment values first and then User. I tried changing User with Equipment and vice versa, but didn't work out well. 
Basically, I want to display all these three tables into one singular table in this order:

```
User Name || User Email || Dept_ID || Dept_NAME || EQUIP_ID || Is_Fullset
```

Please let me know if I need to change my models or query. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = (User
         .select(User, Equipment, Department)
         .join(Equipment, JOIN.INNER)
         .switch(User)
         .join(Department, JOIN.INNER))
for row in query:
    print(row.user_name, row.email, row.dept_id_fk.dept_id,
          row.dept_id_fk.dept_name, row.equip_id_fk.equip_id,
          row.equip_id_fk.is_fullset)
```

Comment: Thanks alot @coliefer , that worked. I had a question related to it. Some of my user instance has null foreign key and I dont think above suggested query would work for it..
For eg, this is how I am creating new user instance will null foreign key:
 

`user = User.create(
        email=request.form['email_id'],
        user_name=request.form['user_name'],
        dept_id_fk =request.form['dropdown_depts'],
        equip_id_fk=None
    )`

Comment: Secondly, when I try to edit one of the user instance with equipment id, it does show new equipment id on the list but it doesn't update is_fullset(boolean) using your suggested query.

`equip_id = request.form['radioID']
    Equipment.create(
        equip_id=equip_id,
        is_fullset=request.form["radioType"]
    )
    user = User.select().where(User.email == email_id).get()
    user.equip_id_fk = equip_id
    user.save()`
Any help on that would be really appreciated :)